# Element missing after parsing XML using XML::Twig's simplify

Tags: perl, hash, xml-twig

Following code parses a simple `test.xml`:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
my $file = 'test.xml';
my $Hash = $twig->parsefile($file)->simplify();
print Dumper($Hash);
```

test.xml:

```
<entry>
<string>SYNMAKE_LOCATION</string>
<string/>
</entry>
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'string' => [
                      {}
                    ]
        };
```

the expect output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'string' => [
                      'SYNMAKE_LOCATION',
                      {}
                    ]
        };
```

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Perl hashes are not JSON. I've removed the according tags and wording, they are misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `simplify` [doesn't work](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128621).